How to combine per capita data across multiple years for the same region?
I have a decade's worth of yearly per capita data of various datapoints "per 1 million people" for several regions, and I want to get the per capita rate over the whole time period.
I understand that merging per capita data for different regions is wrong because you lose the weight of each dataset; i.e. you can't just add/average/etc. a per capita rate for California with the per capita rate for Wyoming, since California's population is an order of manitude higher, so it's not equivalent.
However, if I'm merely combining consecutive years of the same region, wherein each year's per capita rate was calculated using that year's population, is it valid to simply add the per capita values for all the years together, to get the per capita rate over the whole time period, even though the population is changing slightly from year to year?
For example, if I have some data point for a region whose yearly occurrences per 1 million people is: [1.1, 1.2, 1.3], is it accurate to say that the per capita rate over that 3 year period is 3.6 per million people?
Or, would I have to calculate the raw sum of occurrences, and then divide by the average population per year, or the median, or something?

The same problem also exists when you obtain your data points: the population at which point of the year? If the population can change every month, how did you obtain your yearly occurrences per million people?

CDC projections based on the US Census. 1 record per year, per state.

No.  You have to be careful when dealing with averages because the denominator can change.  Taking your example, when the occurrences per million people were $[1.1,1.2,1.3]$ it would be correct to say the occurrences per million people over those three years were $3.6$ if you had the same people in the region for all three years.  On the other hand, suppose there were $10$ million people in the region for the first two years and $1$ billion people for the third year.  The number of occurrences would be $11+12+1300=1323$ and the number of people-years would be $1020$ million, so there are about $1.3$ occurrences per million people-years.  Multiplying by $3$ you would have about $3.9$ occurrences per million people in $3$ years.

Ok, that makes sense why I can't just add them together, but I don't quite understand what you're saying the correct math is. Are you saying to add the populations of each year together, then divide the raw total of occurrences over the same number of years by that mega-population? So, if the population for each year is: [11 million, 12 million, 13 million] for a total of 36 million, and the raw number of occurrences for those years are: [21, 22, 23] for a total of 66 occurrences; I divide 66 by 36 Million, then scale up by the per capita rate? So, 1.83 per 1 Million people?

You need to be clear what time period is involved.  If you want occurrences per million people-years you total the occurrences, total the people and divide.  If you want occurrences per million people sometime in the three years you average the number of people.  This will be $3$ times as high.

I don't understand. What's the difference is between "per million people-years" and "per million people sometime in the three years"? I'm not a math guy, so maybe I don't have the baseline statistics knowledge that you're assuming I do. :-)

If you have a million people for three years you have three million people-years.  If you have one occurrence per million people-years you will have three occurrences.  If you have one occurrence per million people sometime in the three years you will have one occurrence.

OH! That makes sense. Thank you, sir.
